# Why does sbt report missing libraries for Scala 2.10.2 (since Aug, 1th)?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2, typesafe-activator

I've got a number of Play 2.2.x apps that have been building without problem for months. However, starting on 1 Aug 2014, I started getting the following warnings and errors:

> Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.0 ...
>
> :: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS      module not found:
>   org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2
>
> ==== local: tried
>
> /Users/dpope/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.2/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
>
> repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.2/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ==== Maven Central: tried
>
> repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.2/scala-library-2.10.2.pom
>
> ```
>   module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2
> ```
>
> ==== local: tried
>
> /Users/dpope/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
>
> repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ==== Maven Central: tried
>
> repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/scala-compiler-2.10.2.pom
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2: not found
>
>   :: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2: not found
>
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```
>
> :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS unresolved
>   dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2: not found unresolved
>   dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2: not found Error
>   during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries   (see
>   /Users/dpope/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log) Error: Could not
>   retrieve sbt 0.13.0

(I removed the http: from the urls above)

My build command is:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -jar /opt/sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.0.jar -Dsbt.log.noformat=true clean compile test dist
```

Again, that's been working fine for months and just started having issues on 1 Aug 2014.

Going through update.log, I see there are 404s for the 2 files. Obviously, it makes sense why the job is failing since there are 404s.

Anyone have any kind of workaround? Since this is happening pre-Play build, there doesn't appear to be any configs that I can set. I don't have the ability to manage repos via ~/.sbt/repositories on our build server since they are ephemeral.

**EDIT 2 Aug 10:40a EDT**

After a little more digging, it looks like

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.0/ivys/ivy.xml

has dependencies on

```
<override org="org.scala-lang" module="scala-library" matcher="exact" rev="2.10.2"/>
<override org="org.scala-lang" module="scala-compiler" matcher="exact" rev="2.10.2"/>
```

but those no longer exist in any ivy repos.

Comment: Hopefully this should get fixed soon, but until then: scala 2.10.2 is still available in the sonatype release repo. Adding `Resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")` to `/project/plugins.sbt` (and possibly `/build.sbt` too, dependending on your project) should work around this.

Comment: Just found that reported, too, but mind the case for `resolvers` - it starts with the lowercase `r`.

Answer (score 4):

I've just found two places where the issue was reported and solved differently.

### Change resolvers to include Sonatype Releases

It's described in [SI-8772 Builds relying on Scala 2.10.2 artifact in Maven are failing](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8772) and the solution is to add the following to your build:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
```

### Manually downloading the required files

The missing Scala 2.10.2 libraries issue was also reported in [Apache Spark users mailing list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Compiling-Spark-master-284771ef-with-sbt-sbt-assembly-fails-on-EC2-tp11155p11285.html) and the solution was to download the required files manually as follows:

```
$ cd ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/
$ mkdir -p scala-library && cd scala-library
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peterklipfel/scala_koans/master/ivyrepo/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/ivy-2.10.2.xml
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peterklipfel/scala_koans/master/ivyrepo/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/ivydata-2.10.2.properties
$ mkdir -p jars && cd jars
$ wget https://github.com/peterklipfel/scala_koans/raw/master/ivyrepo/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.2.jar
```

It boils down to downloading the missing files from another repository to your Ivy2 local cache. Do the same for `scala-compiler` and you should be all fine.