# Play 2.2.2 + Heroku = unresolved dependencies

Tags: heroku, playframework, dependency-management

I'm trying to deploy a vanilla Play 2.2.2 application. All the code is from running `play new myapp`, I've changed nothing. I added the Heroku remote and received this as a result for an initial push:

```
==== Maven Central: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/scala-compiler-2.10.2.pom

  -- artifact org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2!scala-compiler.jar:

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2: not found

  :: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2: not found

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



  :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
  unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2: not found
  unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2: not found
  Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/.sbt_home/boot/update.log for complete log)
  Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.0
  !     Failed to build app with sbt

  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - Java app

  To git@heroku.com:bmc.git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:bmc.git'
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this (adding the typesafe resolver didn't help, either).

```
name := "myapp"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)     
resolvers := Seq("typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/")

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current solution is to change the sbt version you are using. This is not a heroku issue which you can see in this question which is regarding the same problem but without any Heroku connection: [Why does sbt report missing libraries for Scala 2.10.2 (since Aug, 1th)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095692/why-is-sbt-0-13-0-reporting-org-scala-langscala-library2-10-2-not-found-for-p)

What I did was that I went int the file *build.properties* (under project) and changed the sbt version from 0.13.0 to 0.13.5.

The only line in my build.properties is currently this one

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

Comment: It might be a bit more of a workaround than a solution, but glad it worked =)